# Como enmascarar la ip que aparece en el URL?

Tags: html, web, redes, ip, red

espero se encuentren bien.
Estoy teniendo una complicacion con la construccion de mi pagina web, resulta que tengo una opcion de mi pagina donde puedo descargar PDF pero estos PDF se encuentran alojados en un servidor local el cual tiene una ruta tal cual como: 190:11:77:222:8080/pdf y pues se busca que el sitio sea abierto al publico por lo que dejar esta ip  y el puerto no se considera seguro, mi duda es la siguiente.
¿de que manera puedo ocultar esta ip que aparece ?

cabe aclarar que el codigo es el siguiente

```
<td>
<button class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success"  onclick="window.location.href='http://190.xx.xx.xxx:8080/pdfinformes/<?php echo $fila[0]?>.pdf'" > PDF </button>
</td>
```

el echo que hace es para validar el pdf de cada usuario y asi vaya a esa ruta

Comment: Realiza las descargas a través de un script del lado del servidor, por ejemplo, en PHP puedes usar [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/curl.examples-basic.php) para obtener el archivo y enviarlo al navegador. También se podría con [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile) si la directiva `allow_url_fopen` está activada.

Comment: como podria usar cURL en el caso del button que se tiene? ojo que esta dentro de un foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero crear un script PHP en tu web actual y realices desde ahí la descarga.

En los botones, solo cambia la URL para seguir dentro de la misma web, enviando el nombre de archivo por parámetro:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success"
  onclick="window.location.href='pdfinformes.php?pdf=<?php echo $fila[0]?>'" > PDF </button>
```

En pdfinformes.php recibes el parámetro y realizas la descarga. Suponiendo la directiva `allow_url_fopen` está activa, se puede hacer con [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile):

```
<?php
$file = (isset($_GET['pdf'])) ? $_GET['pdf'] : '';
if($file == '') {
    die('No se proporcionó archivo para descarga');
}
// Aquí deberías aplicar alguna validación adicional
// ------
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
// Nombre del archivo
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'.pdf"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
// Descargar archivo desde el otro servidor y enviar al navegador
readfile('http://ip/ruta/' . $file . '.pdf');
```

En caso de que quieras realizarlo con cURL, solo adapta el código.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te comento; en la ultima parte del codigo en el readfile pues la direccion deberia ser : 'http://190.xx.xx.xxx:8080/pdfinformes/ . $file . '.pdf' pero de esa manera el documento llega en blanco. Pero cuando pongo el nombr del PDF en directo como por ejemplo: 'http://190.x.xxx.xxx:8080/pdfinformes/ IE-22-222. '.pdf' Pues de esa manera si lo descarga, Cabe resaltar que el parametro $file devuelve el mismo valor que el nombre del pdf es decir el "IE-22-222"

Comment: ¿@JeffreyArmijos, el resultado en ambos casos es con `readfile()`? Si es así, solo revisa que la ruta esté correcta. `'http://190.x.xxx.xxx:8080/pdfinformes/' . $file . '.pdf'`

Comment: Si, logré absolverlo, faltaba una comilla simple al finalizar la ruta textual, por eso no anisaba el parámetro de la variable file, gracias por tu ayuda!